# super initWIthCoder return parent type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding, initwithcoder

I think I'm missing something basic...

I implemented a class with `NSCoding` and a child with `NSCoding` too, but when I call the `initWithCoder` of the child class , I get an `InvalidArgument` error.

```
@interface Parent: NSObject<NSCoding>;


@implementation Parent

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
  self = [[Parent alloc] init];

  return self;
}
@end

@interface Child: Parent<NSCoding>;


@implementation Child

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]; //self is Parent type here
  // self = [[Child alloc] init]; if i do that, no error but no init for the parent'attribute
  if(self){
    self.childAttribute = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"KeyAttribute"]; // invalide argument ==> setChildAttribute doesn't exist. 
  }
  return self;
}
```

I must have forgotten something basic, but I can't find out what...
Anybody have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `Parent` in the wrong way. When `-initWithCoder:` is called, the class has already been allocated.   Remember the syntax:

```
id myObj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithArgument:...];
```

so it is assumed that within initializers you don't allocate, you set up default values.

You can refer to the ObjectiveC documentation to see how this should be done. **I strongly recommend to check this out: [Concepts in ObjC Programming – Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)**.
Also the [Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) can be very helpful. ObjectiveC relies on several conventions that you should be aware of to avoid leaks that might become difficult to track.

The right way of initializing your parent is:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init]; // it's just a subclass of NSObject
    if (self) {
        // DECODE VARIABLES...
    }
    return self;
}
```

If `Parent` were a subclass of another `NSCoding`-compliant class, `[super init]` should have been replaced by `[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]`; but in no case within an initializer you set `self` to something that has not been returned by a superclass `-init...` method.

You get the error because when you call `[Child alloc]`, an instance of `Child` is allocated, but then during initialization of `Parent` you return the `Parent` instance you manually allocated, therefore you lost the original reference to `Child` and the class does not match anymore.

Comment: ah the end of day's bugs... i should't post on stackoverflow after a long day of work.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The returned object from your Parent class initialization function is probably the cause.  You need to keep initializing its parent with the initWithCoder: function.  Now it should just be returning a simple NSObject object with no childAttribute property.

With all else hooked up properly it should just need to be:

```
@implementation Parent

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, the role of `-init` is to provide *initialization*, not *allocation*, see the answer above. `[Parent alloc]` doesn't allocate space for `Child` instance variables. The purpose of the method is to initialize `Parent`'s variables, unaware of which (sub)class was allocated, so that `Child` later on can initialize its own. Like this, you would leak the `[Child alloc]` memory, and likely cause some EXC_BAD_ACCESS when `Child` try to access a variable that wasn't defined in `Parent`.

Comment: I just accidentally typed the alloc, thx for the down vote pff

Comment: I couldn't know it was a typo, and with that the answer was wrong. That's why you can remove a downvote after an edit. Remember that I lose 1 reputation too when I downvote: the purpose is clarifying not punishing, or I wouldn't have left a comment too.